# Recently disinfected laptop still has strange issues

Tags: windows, virus

This computer was heavily infected with viruses recently. The hard drive had to be taken out and cleaned by a different machine. The hard drive is now virus free, but Windows still has some strange issues that I need some help fixing.

I've re-installed Chrome, but I still have issues with it. It's the same for Firefox and any other browser. When I plug in a USB flash drive, everything is fine, except when it asks me what to do with it I get what you see in the third image.

I believe this is Windows 7. Any ideas? Here are the images of some of the issues:

[image: If I got to super user on the laptop this is what super user looks like]

[image: Heres what google options looks like]

[image: This is what I get when I plug in a usb.]

Comment: "The hard drive is now virus clean" – well, it's not really unless you completely wipe it and reinstall Windows, I'd say.

Comment: well, as virus clean as my tools can get it.

Comment: You `believe` this is Windows 7, yet you have the knowledge to take out the HD and clean it with another computer?

Comment: That is correct ekaj. Idk why I said believe. It's windows 7 alright. I do know how to remove virus properly, believe it or not (: 

rougefix, combofix, cleanup!, malwayrebyes, and other programs are to be run after that. That's typically how I run a clean virus removal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a repair install of Windows. Put in your Windows 7 DVD, and select the option to Upgrade the current version

Comment: This would be my answer. Or create a new profile and see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 3):

It's better if you do a complete reinstall of the system.
Seems like viruses touched the links between functions and fonts.

Comment: Uhmmm. Yeah, indeed. I want that to be a last option though.

Comment: I know it is the last option, but as a nice recover I don't see, oh wait, you don't have any restore point before virus attack?

Comment: viruses are well known to infect older restore points, bad idea, it may fully re-infect the PC.

Answer (score 1):

Either use an old system backup you have, use a Windows repair disk, or reinstall Windows completely. I would try these steps in this order, from convenient to most inconvenient.